# PHP inserting \ into sql table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am using html form text inputs and CKEditor to allow a client to insert posts into a blog database. The image input takes an html img tag, such as  and the CKEditor also sends over img tags if you choose to insert an image.

My problem is that PHP is inserting a backslash for the quotes in the img tags, I just am not certain how to prevent this. I looked at the documentation but don't want to do anything that would cause harm. Any suggestions? It's been a while since I used PHP and SQL.

```
// set parameters and execute
    $title = $_POST['postBlogTitle'];
    $content = $_POST['editor1'];
    $image = $_POST['postBlogImage'];

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Blog (TITLE, CONTENT, IMAGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $title, $content, $image);
```

Comment: what type is the image column? string?

Comment: @Jay varchar for both the image and content columns.

Comment: My guess is you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled in your PHP configuration. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: @Barmar It says magic_quotes_gpc was deprecated in my version of PHP. Should I just use $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['postBlogImage']); ?

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean removed. Do you have it disabled or not?

Comment: If it's enabled, use `stripslashes` to remove the extraneous backslases.

Comment: If you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, that will add ANOTHER backslash, not remove it.

Comment: @Barmar Duh, that makes sense. So I cant figure out how to find out if it is enabled or not. I am assuming it is. I will try stripslashes. Will this leave risk of injection? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Check your `php.ini`.

Comment: Since you're using prepared statements, there's no risk of injection.

Comment: @Barmar Got it, I did a phpinfo and it is turned on. I will use  stripslashes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help those that may see this in the future:

To test if magic_quotes_gpc is turned on:

Paste the code below in a php file and upload the file to your site in the same folder as your index.html. Visit the url (www.myWebsite.com/phpinfo.php)

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Scroll down and you will eventually find it along with the status.   As @Barmar stated, if turned on, use stripslashes().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) .

```
$image = stripslashes($_POST['postBlogImage']);
```